# Hide the Tool tip popup after all condition are fulfilled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery password live validation form **[HERE](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/01/password-strength-verification-with-jquery/)**

This example guides to add proper password and show with red and green sign.

But I am wanting something like when all the conditions of password are successful then popup tool tip will automatically disappear.

How can this possible. I am not good at jquery, any help will be much appreciated.

[**live JS fiddle link**](http://jsfiddle.net/saifrahu28/cxA5c/1/)

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('input[type=password]').keyup(function() {

        // set password variable
        var pswd = $(this).val();
        if ( pswd.length < 8 ) {
                $('#length').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
            } else {
                $('#length').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
            }


                    //validate letter
            if ( pswd.match(/[A-z]/) ) {
                $('#letter').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
            } else {
                $('#letter').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
            }

            //validate capital letter
            if ( pswd.match(/[A-Z]/) ) {
                $('#capital').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
            } else {
                $('#capital').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
            }

            //validate number
            if ( pswd.match(/\d/) ) {
                $('#number').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
            } else {
                $('#number').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
            }   


    });
    $('input[type=password]').focus(function() {
        // focus code here
    });
    $('input[type=password]').blur(function() {
        // blur code here
    });

    $('input[type=password]').keyup(function() {

    // keyup code here
    }).focus(function() {
        $('#pswd_info').show();
    }).blur(function() {
        $('#pswd_info').hide();
    });


});
```

Comment: The validate letter and validate capital letter rules are redundant. If Validate capital letter is true, so is validate letter. You can have a password like `1234567A`, which is probably not what was meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to count the number of valid rules and when you reach the appropriate number, fade the rules out:

```
if ($('#pswd_info li.valid').length == 4) $('#pswd_info').fadeOut();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cxA5c/4/)**

Comment: Hello Thank you for the best answer. I have one additional one question like with your solution when all condition are fine tool tip hides but if I use back space and any condition breaks up popup will rise again ? I am not sure if this is going to very hard . please let me know if you have any idea on this.

Answer (score 0):

This will work inside of your keyup() function:

```
if(pswd.length >= 8 && pswd.match(/[A-z]/) && pswd.match(/\d/)) {
    $('#pswd_info').hide();
}
```

Updated [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cxA5c/3/)

Comment: Yes I have noticed that there is little problem with Capital letter and letter . Both are acting same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cxA5c/7/)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('input[type=password]').keyup(function() {
        var isValid = true;

        // set password variable
        var pswd = $(this).val();
        if ( pswd.length < 8 ) {
                        isValid &= false;
                        $('#length').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
            } else {
                        isValid &= true;
                        $('#length').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
            }


                    //validate letter
            if ( pswd.match(/[A-z]/) ) {
                        isValid &= true;
                        $('#letter').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
            } else {
                isValid &= false;
                        $('#letter').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
            }

            //validate capital letter
            if ( pswd.match(/[A-Z]/) ) {
                         isValid &= true;
                         $('#capital').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
            } else {
                         isValid &= false; 
                         $('#capital').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
            }

            //validate number
            if ( pswd.match(/\d/) ) {
                isValid &= true;
                        $('#number').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
            } else {
                isValid &= false;
                        $('#number').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
            }   

                    if(isValid){
                        $('#pswd_info').hide();
                    }

    });
    $('input[type=password]').focus(function() {
        // focus code here
    });
    $('input[type=password]').blur(function() {
        // blur code here
    });

    $('input[type=password]').keyup(function() {

    // keyup code here
    }).focus(function() {
        $('#pswd_info').show();
    }).blur(function() {
        $('#pswd_info').hide();
    });


});
```

Comment: This is Best I see so far previous one was accepted as there was no answer coming.

also is this possible when all condition fulfilled tool tip hide and if I erase them with backspace again will tool tip will appear ?